# How to read enum int value (without converting via cast) in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, enums

I had the following:

```
public enum SearchSex {
    All = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    Other = 3
}
```

Now I have this, to allow for Flags and bitmasking:

```
public enum SearchSex {
    All = 1,
    Male = 2,
    Female = 4,
    Other = 8
}
```

In production,  I want all of the settings to remain the same as we make this update.  So I have a script that is doing the following:

```
// for each user:  
user.SearchSex= (SearchSex)(Math.Pow(2, (Convert.ToInt32(user.SearchSex) - 1)));
```

I was thinking the Convert.ToInt32 would return the (old) actual integer value from the database, but it's trying to map the integer value to those (new) defined in the Enum definition.  How do I go about reading the raw integer value as it is, even if there is no longer any corresponding Enum value defined?

Comment: What is the type of the column?  Also, don't use `Math.Pow` for bitwise operations.  That's what the `<<` operator (left-shift) is for.

Comment: @BenVoigt enum SearchSex?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I thought you might be using an integer type in the database.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, yes, the enums are being stored as ints in the database.  I had assumed this was the standard means.

Comment: I suggest you use the database to perform the adjustment.  Don't try to pass it through your object persistence layer, when the values don't match.

Comment: @KhanhTO - you're misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: ok, now I get it after reading more carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just execute a query on the database?  Something like

```
UPDATE usertable SET SearchSex = POWER(2, SearchSex);
```

Of course, I recommend you run a select query first.

```
SELECT *, Power(2, SearchSex) AS NewSearchSex FROM usertable;
```

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a C# way to do it but I just used Dapper to hit SQL this way.